# calculate time/space complexity while running program

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity, space-complexity, dsa

I am trying different types of sorting algorithms and I understand the concept of asymptotic time and space complexity.

I am wondering whether we can write some logic in the program itself to calculate the space/time complexity of that algorithm so that we can have a proof that the algorithm behaves as expected?

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can have it time your algorithm with a variety of input lengths, and then infer how the times scale based on the input lengths (eg: does the time scale linearly with as the input increases).

Comment: _Proving_ that the algorithm has the specified worst-case behavior is not really feasible.

Answer (score 0):

With instrumentation you can only measure the time and space used for a specific instance of a problem. Only if you were to enumerate all possible problem instances you'd be able to proof the worst case time and space complexity. In practice this is rather indefeasible.

You'd need to enumerate all possible instance because you don't know which inputs will be hard and which will be easy. For example if you were to test BubbleSort with ordered inputs from 1...n with varying length, you'd never observe the worst case.

Comment: I did not get you point completely. Could you some more info or link in order to clarify your answer.

Comment: Not a problem. But could you tell me which bit is unclear.